# npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I am trying to run "npm install -g firebase-tools" command on linux OS but it gives me the above error every time.On the other hand when I try to run "npx create-react-app app-name" command, it works fine. I searched the solution on the internet but did not find any acceptable solution. Is there any way to fix this problem.

Comment: I get that too - it's just a warning. It should still work OK. If it's not working OK, then you should file an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: I filed an issue there. Is there any way to go on with firebase for the time being?

Comment: As I said, it's just a warning.  You can ignore it.